# Php key value format array

Tags: php, arrays, format, key, key-value

I am getting an array in following format

```
Array(
name[0]=> [ abc ]
          •
          •
          •
)
```

I want it in form of `(key =>value)` format

```
Array(
[0] => abc
)
```

Please suggest php code to get this

Comment: this is output can you please paste the original format of the array?

Comment: what is your input format ? and where is your code?

Answer (score 3):

```
$Newarray= array_flip($your_array);
```

It was pretty simple. Next time please do some research.

Comment: how did you understand the question, even its not clear what is he looking for?

Comment: I think it's pretty clear. He wants to make make the keys-> values and the values->keys.